# How exactly to use asynctask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, lazy-loading

I have been spending days on implementing a file explorer. I am stuck at just one part. Images are loaded too slow! So I moved to asynctask. I am unable to correctly update the imageview holder .
Here is my code:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position,  View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {




    File file=new File(String.valueOf(filenames[position]));
    if(file.isDirectory()){
        img=R.drawable.folder;
    }

    else{
        img=getImage(filenames[position]);
    }


    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        viewHolder.cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        viewHolder.iv= (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        viewHolder.cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
                myList.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked()); // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.
            }
        });
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.textView1, viewHolder.tv);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.checkBox1, viewHolder.cb);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.checkBox1, viewHolder.iv);
    }
    else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.iv.getLayoutParams().height = 80;
    viewHolder.iv.getLayoutParams().width = 80;
    viewHolder.cb.setTag(position);
    final ViewHolder ViewHolder= viewHolder;

    ViewHolder.tv.setText(myList.get(position).getName());
    ViewHolder.cb.setChecked(myList.get(position).isSelected());

    Log.v("this","viewHolderMT: "+String.valueOf(viewHolder)+"position: "+position);

    final View finalConvertView = convertView;

    class myTask extends AsyncTask<Integer,Bitmap,Bitmap>{

        int pos;
        public myTask(int pos){
            this.pos=pos;
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            Bitmap thumb=null;
            //Log.v("this","position: "+String.valueOf(position));

            if((String.valueOf(filenames[pos])).contains(".jpeg")||String.valueOf(filenames[pos]).contains(".jpg")||String.valueOf(filenames[pos]).contains(".png")||String.valueOf(filenames[pos]).contains(".bmp")||String.valueOf(filenames[pos]).contains(".webp")||String.valueOf(filenames[pos]).contains(".gif")){
                thumb = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String.valueOf(filenames[pos])), 64, 64);
                publishProgress(thumb);
                Log.v("this","In DIB: "+String.valueOf(thumb));
                //Log.v("this","filenameDOI: "+String.valueOf(filenames[pos])+" positionDOI: "+String.valueOf(pos));
            }
            else if((String.valueOf(filenames[pos])).contains(".mp4")||String.valueOf(filenames[pos]).contains(".mkv")||String.valueOf(filenames[pos]).contains(".webm")||String.valueOf(filenames[pos]).contains(".3gp")||String.valueOf(filenames[pos]).contains(".3gpp")){
                thumb=ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filenames[pos].getPath(), MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
                Log.v("this","In DIB: "+String.valueOf(thumb));
                publishProgress(thumb);

            }
            return thumb;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Bitmap... thumb){
            if(isCancelled()){
                return;
            }

            ViewHolder v= (ViewHolder)finalConvertView.getTag();

            Log.v("this","viewHolderPU: "+String.valueOf(v)+"position: "+pos);
            if((String.valueOf(filenames[pos])).contains(".jpeg")||String.valueOf(filenames[pos]).contains(".jpg")||String.valueOf(filenames[pos]).contains(".png")||String.valueOf(filenames[pos]).contains(".bmp")||String.valueOf(filenames[pos]).contains(".webp")||String.valueOf(filenames[pos]).contains(".gif")){
                //Log.v("this","filenameOPE: "+String.valueOf(filenames[pos])+" positionOPE: "+String.valueOf(pos));
                v.iv.setImageBitmap(thumb[0]);
                Log.v("this","In PU: "+String.valueOf(thumb[0]));
            }
            else if((String.valueOf(filenames[pos])).contains(".mp4")||String.valueOf(filenames[pos]).contains(".mkv")||String.valueOf(filenames[pos]).contains(".webm")||String.valueOf(filenames[pos]).contains(".3gp")||String.valueOf(filenames[pos]).contains(".3gpp")){

                v.iv.setImageBitmap(thumb[0]);
            }
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap thumb){



        }
    }

    myTask m=new myTask(position);
    m.execute();

   return convertView;



}
```

Images load up to different imageviews, also the imageviews keep on blinking with new images on both scrolling and otherwise. I am this close to the solution but somehow still stuck.

Comment: And there is really no sense in downvoting the question if you dont know the solution.

Comment: The items of the listview get recycled/reused if you scroll. At the moment you have a thumnail the imageview of that item is already used for a differend thumbnail. Pretty standard. Tons of programmers have encountered this recycling problem.

Comment: @greenapps I understand that. And I have tackeld that using setTag. But the problem exists even if I don't even scoll

Comment: @greenapps For example: Let there be 6 images out of 18 items in my list view. Each item is correctly position and tagged using setTag. I checked that using log. On scrolling they maintain their tags and position. But even if I don't scroll only the last item i.e 6th has flickering thumbnails and other 5 don't have(only they have is the default set through drawable).

Comment: So recycling isnt the problem? You only have some flickering?

Comment: @greenapps Yes! And in each flicker thumbnails are changing! Do you suggest using asynctask inside getView?

Comment: What do you mean with thumbnail is changing? Come to the point please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145302/discussion-between-vidor-vistrom-and-greenapps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get result from AsyncTask in `onPostExecute()` . The `onProgressUpdate()` is there for things like showing progress bar on the UI and things like that.

Try moving your code from `onProgressUpdate()` to `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: Tried that... The actual problem is with tag. In post execute Tags are mismatched. Verified that using log.